# JS - get array from obejct

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript,

How can I sort all of names in one array ?

Is this names in array in object in array in object ? (complicated to explain)

I want something like data = ["Albanie", "Autriche", "Biélorussie", ... ]

```
const obj = {
  "A": [
     {
      "avatar": 1,
      "id": "355",
      "name": "Albanie",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 6,
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Autriche",
    },
  ],
  "B": [
     {
      "avatar": 7,
      "id": "32",
      "name": "Belgique",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 8,
      "id": "375",
      "name": "Biélorussie",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 10,
      "id": "359",
      "name": "Bulgarie",
    },
  ],
  "C": [
     {
      "avatar": 11,
      "id": "(+357)",
      "name": "Chypre",
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how that can be done, based on your example ...

```js
const obj = {
  "A": [
     {
      "avatar": 1,
      "id": "355",
      "name": "Albanie",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 6,
      "id": "43",
      "name": "Autriche",
    },
  ],
  "B": [
     {
      "avatar": 7,
      "id": "32",
      "name": "Belgique",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 8,
      "id": "375",
      "name": "Biélorussie",
    },
     {
      "avatar": 10,
      "id": "359",
      "name": "Bulgarie",
    },
  ],
  "C": [
     {
      "avatar": 11,
      "id": "(+357)",
      "name": "Chypre",
    },
  ]
};

const names = Object.values(obj).flat().map(item => item.name);
console.log(names);

// [ "Albanie", "Autriche", "Belgique", "Biélorussie", "Bulgarie", "Chypre" ]
```

Comment: @EmielZuurbier it has to be flattened first and then mapped.

Answer (score 0):

With all the current goodies, it should be as short as this:

```
data = Object.values( input ).flatMap( (el) => el.name );
```